# How can I change the height of the textarea in Wordpress administration?

Tags: wordpress

I'm referring to the blog administration section. The textarea height is set to 209px inline. How can i change this? I used a program to do a full search within all pages and it couldnt find it. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about the area for writing new posts, can't you just change the setting under Settings | Writing | Size of the post box?

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell exactly from your question, but it sound like there is an inline style="" attribute setting a textarea height.  If you do not have control of the server side source code but you are using some kind of CMS system where you can include JavaScript in the page, If so, you could change the style attribute that way.

Answer (score 0):

The new versions of wordpress have a subtle arrow on the bottom right of content boxes that will allow you to stretch to size. Sometimes I have to adjust the browser window so I can grab and stretch.